# Is it appropriate to suggest edits to duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, editing, closed-questions, duplicates

This question [Can I reference the abstract?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/27179/17966) is a duplicate but I found it by searching and the title confused me. It's actually about "Can I reference other things in my abstract?". I wanted to suggest an edit of the tile but the question *is* a duplicate.

Should I suggest edits to duplicate and/or closed questions?

Comment: Related: [Editing questions that are closed for being off-topic without resolving the reason for the closure](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/editing-questions-that-are-closed-for-being-off-topic-without-resolving-the-reas)

Answer (score 6):

I would distinguish between duplicate question, non-duplicate questions that on hold and could possibly be reopened, and non-duplicate questions that are on hold and have no chance of being reopened (e.g. are wildly off topic).

- **Duplicate questions** are not going to be deleted; they should reflect the quality we expect of all questions on this site, and if they do not, edits are perfectly valid. As with other questions (including open questions), edits should *significantly* improve the post.
- **On hold/closed questions that are not duplicates and could be improved** *should* be. That's the point of putting them on hold in the first place.
- **On hold/closed questions that are not duplicates and will never be reopened** in anything resembling their current form (for example, because they are shopping questions, or wildly off topic for this site) and are subject to [automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) shouldn't be edited in most cases (removing offensive content or profanities is a notable exception). Editing closed questions pushes them into the [reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work). It seems pointless to create unnecessary work for reviewers, for questions that are certainly going to be deleted soon anyways.

Comment: Your second point is pretty important. People sometimes forget that the point of putting questions "on hold" is to improve them to the point where they can be opened back up.

Answer (score -2):

In general, we will only correct questions placed "on hold" (or closed, or duplicate, etc.) if **the title** has a grammatical error or typo, which should *always* be corrected, as the question titles are the main "interface" presented to visitors. Other edits are likely to be unproductive.